# Sharepoint 2010 Notifications across web applications

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have several SharePoint websites.  I'd like to be able to send update notifications from one website to the others. Is there anything that can do this without purchasing 3rd party software?  We are on a very limited budget.  We do not have Exchange capabilities.

Thank you in advance,
Tara

Comment: This question is too broad... What have you tried already? What do you mean by update notifications - when a list item is updated, new document uploaded, etc. on one site you want to notify the other sites that this action has occured? In what manner do you want to use this information on the other sites? And were you looking to develop something custom or implement a (possibly) existing SharePoint feature? If you're not looking to do any actual custom development, this question would likely be better suited for the SharePoint StackExchange site, once it has been updated with more detail.

Comment: When we make a change that affects all of our SharePoint sites, I'd like to send a notice that the change has been implemented or even send a notice that the site will be down for whatever amount of time while updates are done.  It's more of an IT change than a list or document library change.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a central site that is used just for notices, search crawl into a specific "notices" content source, and have all of your disparate sites have a web part to read the search content of that type (shared/not locked down) and display in a CSS-formatted web part so it's consistent messaging across all sites??  That way it's a business-process rather than relying on a "Send" or push mechanism you are simply relying on an updated search and the notice is then relatively immediate wherever the web part resides...